# QUERY to show friends list of a user SQL-Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to build something like a socialnetwork and I have to display the friends list of the current user logged in. I need just a genera query don't worry about passing parameters. I must have 1 record for each friendship, for example if user 1 is friend with user 2 I can't have user 2 is friend with user 1. I must work with 1 record for each friendship, for example if user 1 is friend with user 2, user 1 must have in his list user 2 and user must have user 1 in his list.

ID_User, ID_Friend
1 - 2

SQL: Show me the friend of User with id 1
result: 2
and
SQL: Show me the friend of User with id 2
result: 1

P.S. If you think that this E/R doesn't work let me know thanks!
TABLE USER

```
drop table if exists Utente CASCADE ;
create table Utente (
ID_Utente int UNSIGNED not null primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
Username  varchar(50) not null UNIQUE,
Pswd varchar(30) not null,
Nome varchar(30) not null,
Cognome varchar(20) not null,
Email varchar(50) not null,
Data_Nascita date not null
);
```

TABLE FREINDSHIP

```
drop table if exists Amicizia CASCADE ;
create table Amicizia (
Username1_ID_Utente int UNSIGNED not null,
Username2_ID_Utente int UNSIGNED not null,
PRIMARY KEY (Username1_ID_Utente, Username2_ID_Utente),
FOREIGN KEY (Username1_ID_Utente) REFERENCES Utente(ID_Utente),
FOREIGN KEY (Username2_ID_Utente) REFERENCES Utente(ID_Utente)
);
```

INSERT

```
DELETE FROM casestudy.utente;

INSERT INTO casestudy.utente(ID_Utente, Username, Pswd, Nome, Cognome, Email, Data_Nascita)
VALUES (NULL,'giovannirossini','giovanni','giovanni','rossi','giovanni@gmail.com','1990-09-09');
INSERT INTO casestudy.utente(ID_Utente, Username, Pswd, Nome, Cognome, Email, Data_Nascita)
VALUES (NULL,'michelabianchi','michela','michela','bianchi','michela@gmail.com','1990-08-08');
INSERT INTO casestudy.utente(ID_Utente, Username, Pswd, Nome, Cognome, Email, Data_Nascita)
VALUES (NULL,'filippoverdi','filippo','filippo','verdi','filippo@gmail.com','1990-07-07');
INSERT INTO casestudy.utente(ID_Utente, Username, Pswd, Nome, Cognome, Email, Data_Nascita)
VALUES (NULL,'giannineri','gianni','gianni','neri','gianni@gmail.com','1990-06-06');
INSERT INTO casestudy.utente(ID_Utente, Username, Pswd, Nome, Cognome, Email, Data_Nascita)
VALUES (NULL,'giuliaangelucci','giulia','giulia','angelucci','giulia@gmail.com','1990-05-05');

DELETE FROM casestudy.amicizia;
INSERT INTO casestudy.amicizia(Username1_ID_Utente, Username2_ID_Utente)
VALUES (3,4);
INSERT INTO casestudy.amicizia(Username1_ID_Utente, Username2_ID_Utente) 
VALUES (1,3);
INSERT INTO casestudy.amicizia(Username1_ID_Utente, Username2_ID_Utente) 
VALUES (5,3);
INSERT INTO casestudy.amicizia(Username1_ID_Utente, Username2_ID_Utente) 
VALUES (2,3);
INSERT INTO casestudy.amicizia(Username1_ID_Utente, Username2_ID_Utente) 
VALUES (2,5);
```

[Table Utente](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgN67.png)

[Table Amicizia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rV31m.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your question correctly you simply need a query that checks if the user you are building the friendship list for is in the first or second column of your juction table (and join to the user table to get all needed information).

I think this should work:

```
select * from Utente u1
JOIN Amicizia a ON 
u1.ID_Utente =  a.Username1_ID_Utente
JOIN Utente u2 ON
u2.ID_Utente =  a.Username2_ID_Utente
WHERE a.Username1_ID_Utente = "your_User" OR a.Username2_ID_Utente = "your_User"
```